# Push only contents below UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

Ok so in my app, there are various custom interactable pop ups appearing. However the problems begin when I need to push to the next UIViewController. To tackle this, I created a full screen UIViewController with a semi-transparent background and a hidden navigation bar. I then added a navigation bar to the pop up and called the push function when the relevant button is tapped. However the result is rather ugly, as the entire UIViewController moves and not just what is below the navigation bar. What I want to do is something like the push animation on the Twitter or Facebook iOS 7 widgets, where only the actual pop up pushes. Anybody got any idea about that? I've been searching for hours, even in this site and I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: I think this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21343502/presenting-a-uinavigationcontroller-in-a-custom-modal

Comment: @PiotrTomasik Thanks, it's rather helpful, though the animation, even in that occasion is full screen. If you're on your iPhone, open the Twitter compose widget, say by going to Photos > Share > Twitter > Account and you'll see what I mean. But, even this overlap looks nicer than my ugly push, so I might consider it, thanks :)

Comment: Yeah, I know exactly what you're talking about `SLComposeViewController`.  I think that you can acheive a similiarly sized modal using the example code in that linked question. CGRect finalFrame = CGRectInset(presentationView.frame, 10, 20);
    modalView.frame = CGRectOffset(finalFrame, 0, CGRectGetHeight(presentationView.frame));

Comment: @PiotrTomasik Thank you, that could work actually :) I'll try it and I'll let you know