# Why is UINavigationBar shrinking after animation?

Tags: ios

I tried to follow this question: [Presenting a UINavigationController in a custom modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21343502/presenting-a-uinavigationcontroller-in-a-custom-modal), but my navigation bar is shrinking from 64p to 44p after the animation. I'm using a custom `UIPresentationController` and `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`.

I think the problem is with the following code. When I comment out the animation it the navigation bar starts out and remains at 44p

```
func animatePresentationWithTransitionContext(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
    let presentedController = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey)! as DrawerNavigationController
    let presentedControllerView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextToViewKey)!
    let containerView = transitionContext.containerView()

    var finalFrame = transitionContext.finalFrameForViewController(presentedController)
    presentedControllerView.frame = CGRectOffset(finalFrame, 0, containerView.bounds.size.height)
    containerView.addSubview(presentedControllerView)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(self.duration, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: .AllowUserInteraction, animations: {

        var height = presentedController.height()
        presentedControllerView.frame.origin.y = containerView.bounds.size.height - height

        }, completion: {(completed: Bool) -> Void in
            transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
    })
}
```